# How are the Divergence Number and world line related?

Tags: steins-gate

In *Steins;Gate* there is much ado about the Divergence Number of the current world line. But if I am remembering correctly, the meter Kyouma made/carries/is given shows the difference between the current world line and the "previous" one—which I understood to be the one Okabe was in immediately before his last time jump.

Does the Divergence Number work relative to the last time jump–originating world line, or relative to the world line where it was constructed (the world line where SERN maintains a dystopia)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Steins;Gate there is an important thing called Attractor Field. An Attractor field is a number of world lines that may be slightly different from each other in small details, but provide the same end result.

Each attractor field is "made of" a number of World lines, in some range. For example, the Alpha Attractor Field contains world lines with the divergence from 0% to 0.99%, the Beta Attractor has world lines from 1% to 1.99% and so on.

Thus, the divergence meter is not showing some relative value, but rather an absolute value which is used to determine the Attractor field that the current World Line belongs to.

[Source.](http://steins-gate.wikia.com/wiki/Attractor_Field)

Comment: This might be nitpicking the science a bit too far, but it seems like there could very possibly be more world lines in an Attractor Field than can be displayed on the gauge. Presumably an infinite number of decimal places are possible in theory, just not displayable in practice. Same goes for the number of Attractor Fields themselves; surely, there might be more than 100 of them, theoretically.